# Change document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code in vanilla JS (javascript). I searched a lot of tutorial documents and videos for changing this code to React.

Following is the code in simple javascript

```
const Children = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].children;
Array.from(sliderChildren).forEach((child) => {    
  });
```

Can anyone please help me how do this in react?

Comment: Actually, React allows you to manipulate the DOM without necessarily using the document object. It would help if you point out what exactly you want to accomplish so we can show you how it is done in React.

Comment: Please add a minimal working code example (Basic HTML - JS snippet). Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: React requires a whole new file system to typical vanilla JS. So would recommend [this online IDE](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and check out [this react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you just would *not* use DOM methods like `getElementsByClassName` in React.

By design, React doesn't "know" about the DOM elements at all, it only knows about its state, then renders the DOM elements from the state, and then "forgets" about the DOM elements again.

You may think this way:
you do not develop vanilla JS and HTML anymore, *instead* you develop React.

Anyway, if you really need it for some reason, you need to find a way to "manually" tell react that the DOM node is ready to be accessed. There is no way to "automatically" make React aware of the current state of DOM elements.

*Note that you can not use something like `window.onload` for that, because that again is a methond from the DOM world as well.*

e.g.:

```
export const SomeList = (props)=>{
    const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    return (<div className="someParent">
        { list.map((item)=> <p className="someChildren">number { item }</p>) }
    </div>);
};

export const AccessDom = (props)=>{

    const accessDomNodes = function(){
        const Children = document.getElementsByClassName("someParent")[0].children;
        console.log('Children:', Children);
    };

    return (<div>
        <SomeList />
        <button type="button" onClick={ accessDomNodes }>
            I'm sure the DOM node exists now
        </button>
    </div>);
};
```

If you want to do something with the DOM elements in React, you need to pass it over into the React world by setting some React state:

```
export const AccessDom = (props)=>{
    const [ childsList, setChildsList ] = useState([]); // <-- a React state

    const accessDomNodes = function(){
        const Children = document.getElementsByClassName("someParent")[0].children;
        setChildsList( Array.from( Children ) );  // <-- set a React state
        console.log('Children:', Children);
    };

    return (<div>
        <SomeList />
        <button type="button" onClick={ accessDomNodes }>
            I'm sure the DOM node exists now
        </button>
        <div>found children: { childsList.length }</div>
    </div>);
};
```